# command line to find a line and add " before and after the rest of text

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, replace, sed

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
   "User Entries" : [
      {
         "Names" : [
            "root",
            "BUILTIN\\Local System"
         ],
         "Libinfo" : {
               "pw_uuid" : FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000,
               "pw_dir" : "/var/root",
               "pw_shell" : "/bin/sh",
               "pw_name" : "root",
            }
      },
      {
         "Names" : [
            "bob",
            "BUILTIN\\Local System"
         ],
         "Libinfo" : {
               "pw_uuid" : FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA11111111,
               "pw_dir" : "/Users/bob",
               "pw_shell" : "/bin/sh",
               "pw_name" : "bob",
         }
      },
   ]
}
```

What I would like to do is, find the "pw_uuid" lines and add "" to the rest of the line before comma. for example, 
the original line: "pw_uuid" : FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000,
change to: "pw_uuid" : "FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000",

Have a sense of using sed will do it, and any command you bring up is appreciate.

Background: because with jq command, it reports the number is invalid (FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000), actually they are strings. I'm working on a script to test if a specific user, bob in the above, exist, if yes, than pull user info, like, pw_dir and/or pw_uuid etc. I'm studying jq options to get this done, if you have any idea about this, please feel free  also. Thanks,

Comment: You should really fix the process that generates that invalid JSON

Comment: @glenn-jackman, this file is from a native OS X command, "odutil show cache"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can make it:

```
sed '/pw_uuid/s/"pw_uuid" : \([A-Z0-9-]*\)/"pw_uuid" : "\1"/g' file
```

or

```
sed '/pw_uuid/s/\(^[^:]*\): \([A-Z0-9-]*\)/\1: "\2"/g' file
```

So `/pw_uuid/` filters the lines having `pw_uuid`. In those, it replaces the block `"pw_uuid" : XXX` with `"pw_uuid" : "XXX"`.

This is done "catching" the `"pw_uuid"` block and the XXX block. `[A-Z0-90-]*` means: a block of upper case, numbers and `-`. Then they are printed back using the `\1`, `\2` that refers to the "catched" block.

---

To have the file updated with the content, add `-i` to the commmand, like:

```
sed -i.bak '/pw_uuid/s/"pw_uuid" : \([A-Z0-9-]*\)/"pw_uuid" : "\1"/g' file
    ^^^^^^
```

or

```
sed -i.bak '/pw_uuid/s/\(^[^:]*\): \([A-Z0-9-]*\)/\1: "\2"/g' file
    ^^^^^^
```

---

Output of the command

```
{
   "User Entries" : [
      {
         "Names" : [
            "root",
            "BUILTIN\\Local System"
         ],
         "Libinfo" : {
               "pw_uuid" : "FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000",
               "pw_dir" : "/var/root",
               "pw_shell" : "/bin/sh",
               "pw_name" : "root",
            }
      },
      {
         "Names" : [
            "bob",
            "BUILTIN\\Local System"
         ],
         "Libinfo" : {
               "pw_uuid" : "FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA11111111",
               "pw_dir" : "/Users/bob",
               "pw_shell" : "/bin/sh",
               "pw_name" : "bob",
         }
      },
   ]
}
```

Comment: Xanks, you get exactly what I want.

Comment: @user3085367 check my updated answer, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -p -e 's/ : ([^"]+),/ : "$1",/;' < json.test
```

Comment: Wah, this' the most simple answer… Xanks.